# Excel - How to count if certain entries exist in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to see if there are any combinations of two or more of the following keywords in each row: "articles", "instagram", "facebook"

For example:

If row 642 has "articles" and "instagram" return 1,

If row 642 has "instagram" and "facebook" return 1,

If row 642 has "articles" and "facebook" return 1,

etc..

Can anyone help me get started in the right direction?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to count all rows, which has certain conditions? Or do you want to check a specific row only?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
=IF(OR(
      AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("instagram", B2&C2&D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("facebook", B2&C2&D2))),
      AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("articles", B2&C2&D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("facebook", B2&C2&D2))),
      AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("articles", B2&C2&D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("instagram", B2&C2&D2)))
    ),1,0)
```

Where `B1`, `C1` and `D1` in the formula above are the cells in which the words exist.

Result:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work on only one of the combinations, the first column and the third column. Am I using this correctly? Please see screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/pfw8V

Comment: Thanks. It's closer, but I'm getting a 1 where there is only one entry. Please see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/N4f6W.

Comment: I'm looking at row 509, where it has only "sirius".

Comment: Row 509  has both "Serius" and "Radio"

Comment: Ah yes! I should use a different key word then. Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroLee Happy to help. Voting up and accepting my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simply use a count of non-blank cells, for example:

```
=COUNTA(C642:E642)
```

On this row, since you are looking for a combination of 2 or more, you should filter on the results with 2 or more.

Alternatively, if you can change the way you are storing all this information, you could put `1` instead where a certain row has the 'feature':

[image]

With the same logic as previously, just add up the numbers and if it is at or larger than the minimum you are looking for, you can get them almost instantaneously with simple addition.